# How to show retrieval tool links?

Tags: python, openai-api

I am trying to build a Chatbot with OpenAI's new Assistants API.

I got the basic functionality to work, but I can't figure out how to access and display source links the assistant mentions in it's answer. Somehow "file_id" must have that information, but I don't know how to get to it and use it.

I am using Python + Flask.

Below is the code I use for my Flask app. But I think I am just misunderstanding some of the basic functionality of the API and there should be an easy way to get to those links, right?

```
@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    data = request.json 
    user_message = data['message']
    thread_id = session.get('thread_id')

    if not thread_id:
        file = client.files.create(
            file=open("bi.txt", "rb"),
            purpose='assistants'
        )

        assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
            name="SwissVAT Bot",
            instructions="You help businesses look up Swiss VAT regulations. Use bi.txt to find the regulations. You answer only in German. Your user is a lawyer, so always provide chapter number and name where your information is from, otherwise the information is useless.",
            model="gpt-4-1106-preview",
            tools=[{"type": "retrieval"}],
            file_ids=[file.id]
        )
        thread = client.beta.threads.create()
        session['thread_id'] = thread.id
        session['assistant_id'] = assistant.id
        assistant_id = session['assistant_id']
    else:
        thread_id = session['thread_id']
        assistant_id = session['assistant_id']
        thread = client.beta.threads.retrieve(thread_id=thread_id)
    
    # print("Thread ID:", thread_id, "Assistant ID:", assistant_id)
    seen_message_ids = set()

    
    # Add user message to the thread
    user_message_obj = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        role="user",
        content=user_message
    )

    # Update last message ID
    seen_message_ids.add(user_message_obj.id)

    # Run the Assistant
    run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        assistant_id=session['assistant_id'],  # Use assistant_id from the session
        instructions="You help businesses look up Swiss VAT regulations. Use bi.txt to find the regulations. You answer only in German. Your user is a lawyer, so always provide chapter number and name where your information is from, otherwise the information is useless."
    )

    max_wait_time = 60  # Maximum wait time in seconds
    start_time = time.time()

    run_completed = False
    while time.time() - start_time < max_wait_time:
        run_status = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
            thread_id=thread.id,
            run_id=run.id
        )
        # print(run_status)
        if run_status.status == 'completed' or run_status.status == 'failed':
            run_completed = True
            break
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for a short period before checking again

    if not run_completed:
        return jsonify({'response': "The assistant didn't respond in time."})

    # Fetch the assistant's message after run completion    
    messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=thread.id)
    # print(messages)
    
    for message in messages.data:
        if message.role == "assistant":
            # Check for annotations in the message
            if "annotations" in message.content[0].text:
                for annotation in message.content[0].text.annotations:
                    # Look for file_citation annotations
                    if annotation.type == 'file_citation':
                        file_id = annotation.file_citation.file_id
                        # Now you can use this file_id to make a GET request to the API
    try:
        print(file_id)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass
        
    # Initialize a variable to store the full conversation
    full_conversation = ""

    for message in messages.data:
        if message.role == "assistant":
            # Append the main message text
            full_conversation += message.content[0].text.value + " "

            # Check and append annotations (like source links)
            if "annotations" in message.content[0].text:
                for annotation in message.content[0].text.annotations:
                    if annotation.type == 'file_citation':
                        full_conversation += f" Source: {annotation.file_citation.file_id}"  # Format this based on actual link structure

    assistant_message = full_conversation.strip() if full_conversation else "No response."
    return jsonify({'response': assistant_message})
```

What I tried so far:

- extract the link from file_id. However I failed to extract file_id because my program kept crashing when I tried that
- try to solve the problem with ChatGPT, but those suggestions also lead the program to crash